# how to fix a inherited model?

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-views, django-orm

I have an inherited data model:

```
class Unit (models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, default="DEFAULT VALUE")
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="DEFAULT VALUE")
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="DEFAULT VALUE")
    City = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="DEFAULT VALUE")
    State = models.CharField(max_length=2, default="DEFAULT VALUE")
    zip = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    lat = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=9, max_digits=38, null=True)
    lng = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=9, max_digits=38, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Geo (Unit):
    coverage = models.TextField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name

class Ship (Unit):
    HullNumber = models.TextField(null=True)
    ShipClass = models.ForeignKey(ShipClass)
    Origin = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=ALLEGIENCE_CHOICES, default='FED')
    Geo = models.ForeignKey(Geo)
```

The problem is that if I execute:

```
>>> models.Geo._meta.get_all_field_names()
['City', 'Name', 'State', 'address1', 'address2', 'coverage', 'crew', 'description', 'id', 'lat', 'lng', 'ship', 'zip']
```

but if I execute:

```
>>> models.Geo.objects.all()
```

I get:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: fleet_geo.id

am I missing something?  I have been RTFM'ing for the last two days.  I don't know what I'm missing. Does anyone have any light they can shed on this?

Thanks

Comment: Does this problem occur even after migration?

Comment: HI.  Appreciate the attempt.  yes.  I've run the make migrations and migrate functions about six times now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your databases doesn't seem set-up, or up to date with your model.

If using django 1.7+ you have to run the migrations so that your databases tables are created/modified for your model: [Activating Models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/#activating-models)

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: ok.  I'm just going to say I ran those six times....but because you said it, that's when it decided to work.  Magic.  Thanks very much tho.  at least I knew I wasn't that far off.